# Stack Data structure to make web browser

Tags: python, stack

```
from stack import stack        
def getAction():
        '''
        Write docstring to describe function
        Inputs: no arguments taken by this function.
        Returns: string containing users input if he has chosen one of the correct input options
        '''
        correct_input=False
        while correct_input==False:
            user_input=input("Enter = to enter a URL, < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: ")
            if user_input =='q' or user_input =='>' or user_input =='<' or user_input =='=':
                correct_input=True

            if correct_input==False:
                print('Invalid entry.')
        return user_input


    def goToNewSite(current, pages):
        '''
        Write docstring to describe function
        Inputs: index of the current website (int), reference to list containing the webpage addresses to go back and forth between
        Returns: address inputted by user as a string
        '''

        new_web_address=input('Enter a new website address ')
        for i in range(current+1,len(pages)):
            pages.pop()
        pages.append(new_web_address)
        #pages[current+1]=new_web_address
        #pages=pages[:current+1]

        return current+1



    def goBack(current, pages):
        '''
        Write docstring to describe function
        Inputs: index of the current website (int),reference to list containing the webpage addresses to go back and forth between
        Returns: index of the previous webpage (int)
        '''
        # alternatively this could be done by checking if current-1>=0
        if current-1>=0:
            return current-1

        else:
            print('Cannot go backward')
            return current




    def goForward(current, pages):
        '''
        Write docstring to describe function
        Inputs: index of the current website (int),reference to list containing the webpage addresses to go back and forth between
        Returns: index of the previous webpage (int)
        '''  
        # alternatively this could be done by checking if current +1 in range(len(pages))
        if current+1<len(pages):
            return current+1

        else:
            print('Cannot go forward')
            return current




    def main():
        '''
        Controls main flow of web browser simulator
        Inputs: N/A
        Returns: None
        '''    
        HOME = 'www.google.ca'
        websites = [HOME]
        currentIndex = 0
        quit = False

        while not quit:
            print('\nCurrently viewing', websites[currentIndex])
            print(websites)

            action = getAction()

            if action == '=':
                currentIndex = goToNewSite(currentIndex, websites)

            elif action == '<':
                currentIndex = goBack(currentIndex, websites)
            elif action == '>':
                currentIndex = goForward(currentIndex, websites)
            elif action == 'q':
                quit = True

        print('Browser closing...goodbye.')    


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

above is my code

I am supposed to make a web browser simulator using the data structure we were given known as a stack. I've made another version of this without using try except else and using lists but using this new kind of object I am struggling to make several cases work. For example in a trial run of this, it does not give me an error when I attempt to go back after I've entered at least one website even though there are no websites to go back to from the current website.
for example I'll have entered step1 then go back which takes me to www.google.ca and then go back again and instead of saying I cannot go back it will just reprint to the screen. I'm not sure what is going on there and was wondering if someone can explain why this isn't working and the fault in my logic

below is the class we were told to use instances of this Stack class to implement this.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    # MODIFY: RAISE AN EXCEPTION IF THIS METHOD IS INVOKED ON AN EMPTY STACK
    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty()==True:
            raise Exception('Stack is empty cannot pop')
        if self.isEmpty()==False:

            return self.items.pop()

    # MODIFY: RAISE AN EXCEPTION IF THIS METHOD IS INVOKED ON AN EMPTY STACK
    def peek(self):
        if self.isEmpty()==True:
            raise Exception('Stack is empty cannot peek')
        if self.isEmpty()==False:


            return self.items[len(self.items)-1] 

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def show(self):
        print(self.items)

    def __str__(self):
        stackAsString = ''
        for item in self.items:
            stackAsString += item + ' '
        return stackAsString
```

Comment: Varaible and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Using `if ... == True:` is not great, for two different reasons, you can simply stick to `if ... :` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a solution and a homework

**Homework:**

- Could you please complete the go forward method by yourself?

**Note:**
Take a look and what I did and complete the forward method by yourself

```py
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    # MODIFY: RAISE AN EXCEPTION IF THIS METHOD IS INVOKED ON AN EMPTY STACK
    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty()==True:
            raise Exception('Stack is empty cannot pop')
        if self.isEmpty()==False:

            return self.items.pop()

    # MODIFY: RAISE AN EXCEPTION IF THIS METHOD IS INVOKED ON AN EMPTY STACK
    def peek(self):
        if self.isEmpty()==True:
            raise Exception('Stack is empty cannot peek')
        if self.isEmpty()==False:


            return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def show(self):
        print(self.items)

    def __str__(self):
        stackAsString = ''
        for item in self.items:
            stackAsString += item + ' '
        return stackAsString



# from stack import stack
def getAction():
        '''
        Write docstring to describe function
        Inputs: no arguments taken by this function.
        Returns: string containing users input if he has chosen one of the correct input options
        '''
        correct_input=False
        while correct_input==False:
            user_input=input("Enter = to enter a URL, < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: ")
            if user_input =='q' or user_input =='>' or user_input =='<' or user_input =='=':
                correct_input=True

            if correct_input==False:
                print('Invalid entry.')
        return user_input


def goToNewSite(current, pages):
    '''
    Write docstring to describe function
    Inputs: index of the current website (int), reference to list containing the webpage addresses to go back and forth between
    Returns: address inputted by user as a string
    '''

    new_web_address=input('Enter a new website address ')
    # for i in range(current+1,len(pages)):
    #     pages.pop()
    # pages.append(new_web_address)
    pages.push(new_web_address)
    #pages[current+1]=new_web_address
    #pages=pages[:current+1]

    return pages.size()



def goBack(current, pages):
    '''
    Write docstring to describe function
    Inputs: index of the current website (int),reference to list containing the webpage addresses to go back and forth between
    Returns: index of the previous webpage (int)
    '''
    # alternatively this could be done by checking if current-1>=0
    # if current-1>=0:
    #     return current-1
    #
    # else:
    #     print('Cannot go backward')
    #     return current
    if pages.size() <= 1:
        print('Cannot go backward')
        return pages.size()
    pages.pop()
    return pages.size()





def goForward(current, pages):
    '''
    Write docstring to describe function
    Inputs: index of the current website (int),reference to list containing the webpage addresses to go back and forth between
    Returns: index of the previous webpage (int)
    '''
    # alternatively this could be done by checking if current +1 in range(len(pages))
    if current+1<len(pages):
        return current+1

    else:
        print('Cannot go forward')
        return current




def main():
    '''
    Controls main flow of web browser simulator
    Inputs: N/A
    Returns: None
    '''
    HOME = 'www.google.ca'
    # websites = [HOME]
    websites = Stack()
    websites.push(HOME)
    currentIndex = 0
    quit = False

    while not quit:
        # print('\nCurrently viewing', websites[currentIndex])
        print('\nCurrently viewing', websites.peek())
        print(websites)

        action = getAction()

        if action == '=':
            currentIndex = goToNewSite(currentIndex, websites)

        elif action == '<':
            currentIndex = goBack(currentIndex, websites)
        elif action == '>':
            currentIndex = goForward(currentIndex, websites)
        elif action == 'q':
            quit = True

    print('Browser closing...goodbye.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are the outputs

> Currently viewing www.google.ca www.google.ca  Enter = to enter a URL,
>   < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: =    Enter a new website
>   address https://www.pymiami.org
>
> Currently viewing https://www.pymiami.org www.google.ca
>   https://www.pymiami.org  Enter = to enter a URL, < to go back, > to go
>   forward, q to quit: https://www.dabeaz.com Invalid entry. Enter = to
>   enter a URL, < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: = Enter a new
>   website address https://www.dabeaz.com
>
> Currently viewing https://www.dabeaz.com www.google.ca
>   https://www.pymiami.org https://www.dabeaz.com  Enter = to enter a
>   URL, < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: = Enter a new website
>   address https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum
>
> Currently viewing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum
>   www.google.ca https://www.pymiami.org https://www.dabeaz.com
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum  Enter = to enter a
>   URL, < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: <
>
> Currently viewing https://www.dabeaz.com www.google.ca
>   https://www.pymiami.org https://www.dabeaz.com  Enter = to enter a
>   URL, < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: <
>
> Currently viewing https://www.pymiami.org www.google.ca
>   https://www.pymiami.org  Enter = to enter a URL, < to go back, > to go
>   forward, q to quit: <
>
> Currently viewing www.google.ca www.google.ca  Enter = to enter a URL,
>   < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: < Cannot go backward
>
> Currently viewing www.google.ca www.google.ca  Enter = to enter a URL,
>   < to go back, > to go forward, q to quit: